# Генерация имени переменной C-obj

Tags: objective-c

Как в C-Objective сгенерировать имя переменной для проведения методов. Например:
- Есть массив array['vew1','view2','view3'], нужно определить состояние view.hide, соответственно зная только индекс массива. Помогите разобраться, как это реализовать.

Comment: Я ответил, честно говоря, не совсем для себя уяснив, что именно вы хотите сделать. Поэтому лучше добавьте в свой вопрос Objective-C код того, что у вас уже есть, чтобы было более понятно, с чего вы начинаете.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, вы все правильно поняли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// UIView *view1, view2, view3;

NSArray *views = @[ view1, view2, view3 ];

[views enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // view.isHidden...
}];

// или

for (UIView *view in views) {
    // NSUInteger viewIndex = [views indexOfObject:view];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Я думаю вопрошающий имел ввиду valueForKey:@"view1"

Comment: Была такая мысль, просто я захотел убедиться в том, что автор хочет именно этого и что он действительно этого хочет)))

Comment: @AlexDenisov, @Stanislaw Pankevich, да то что нужно, спасибо)